# RN with Firestore unable to wait for Promise to resolve

Tags: react-native, google-cloud-firestore

I have a simple call to Firestore to write a doc and then wait for the doc to finish writing before changing state of the parent. However, the parent state is being changed too fast, resulting in reading fields that I think have not yet been written/propagated. I tried adding a delay with setTimeout and it seems ignored. How can I make sure the state change is absolutely only called after the Firestore doc is written completely?

The code:

```
updateDBEntry(stateObj) {
   var that = this;
   var docRef = firebase.firestore().collection('sessions').doc(this.state.userID);
   docRef.get().then((doc) => {
     if (!doc.exists) {
       const timestamp = firebase.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp();
       var duration = (stateObj.seshDuration) ? stateObj.seshDuration : 1;
       docRef.set({
         seshName: stateObj.seshName,
         seshStreet: stateObj.seshStreet,
         seshZipcode: stateObj.seshZipcode,
         seshDuration: duration,
         seshDesc: stateObj.seshDesc,
         seshTime: timestamp,
       }).then(() => {
         var handleToUpdate  = that.props.handleToUpdate;
         setTimeout(() => {
            handleToUpdate(1); //this changes the parent's state
          }, 10000);
       });
     }
  });

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure exactly the problem you're running into here, mostly because you've only shown this one function, and not how you're using it in the rest of your app.  But I can tell you three things for sure:

1. When the promise from set() resolves successfully, you can be certain the document is written.
2. `get()` and `set()` are asynchronous, and so is `then()`.  They all return promises the represent async work.
3. Item 2 means that your entire function updateDBEntry() is also asynchronous and returns immediately, before any of the work is complete.

Because this entire function is async, when it returns, the document will not have been created yet.  Instead, maybe this function should return that resolves only after all the work is complete, so that the caller can also use it set up some code to execute after the work is done.

Comment: so how can I make this function resolve only after the doc is written?

Comment: I missed a couple words.  This function should return A PROMISE that resolves only after all the work is complete.

Comment: ahhh ok, so basically this function itself needs to return a promise to the caller so that the caller knows the doc has written. will do. thanks